# Cloud function with pubsub trigger executed endlessly when calling gmail API messages.send()

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using the Atlassian Status Page with email automation, which means that it displays an alert on screen whenever it receives an email with subject 'DOWN' and deletes the same alert when it receives an email with subject 'UP'.

I activated the Gmail Pub/Sub (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) push notifications, which watches the gmail inbox for changes and sends a push notification to a pub/sub topic when a change actually happens.

Then I created a cloud function which is triggered by pub/sub notifications. This cloud function should:

1. Read the latest unread email
2. If this email is an alert sent by our 3rd party provider, send a new email to the Status Page with subject 'DOWN' or 'UP' accordingly.

This is the code:

```
def access_oauth2_json():
  ### Code
  return creds_dict


def create_message(subject):
  ### Code
  return {'raw': b64_string}


def send_message(service, message, user_id = 'me'):
  try:
    response = service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()
    return response
  except HttpError as error:
    logging.error('An error occurred:', error)



def update_status_page(arg1,arg2):

  ### Initialise creds

  try:
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    request = {
      'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
      'topicName': 'pubsub_topic_id'
    }
    service.users().watch(userId='me', body = request).execute()

    last_message_info = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD'], q = 'in:inbox is:unread', maxResults=1).execute().get('messages', [])

    last_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=last_message_info[0]['id']).execute()

    header = last_message['payload']['headers']
    sub = ""
    for x in header:
      if x['name'] == 'Subject':
        sub = x['value'] #subject
        logging.info(sub)

    if 'special_alert_string' in sub:
      message = create_message(subject = 'DOWN')
      response = send_message(service, message)
    elif 'other_special_alert_string' in sub:
      message = create_message(subject = 'UP')
      response = send_message(service, message)

  except HttpError as error:
    logging.info(f'An error occurred: {error}')

  return 200
```

What happens is that:

1. When the function is triggered by an email which is **not** a 3rd party alert, the if/elif blocks are not executed, and the cloud function is executed 2 or 3 times (instead of 1, but that's fine for me, so not really a problem)

[image: Highlighted the execution IDs of the functions]

2 - **Problem** - When the function is triggered by an email which **is** a 3rd part alert, the if/elif blocks are executed (one of the 2) and the function is executed endlessly! It only stops because it reaches the maximum API requests per interval of time.

[image]

What I have tried:

1. To remove the watch() line, without success
2. Commenting out the service.users().messages().send() line falls back into case 1, so my guess is that this instruction is triggering a push notification to the pub/sub topic and generates the infinite loop. The issue could maybe solved with another watch() labelId, but I haven't figured out which one.

I hope this is clear, thank you for your help!

Comment: To debug this, I suggest first setting up a simple Cloud Function that does nothing but print the message and responds with a success, so the Cloud Pub/Sub message pushed to the function is acknowledged. Then, once you are able to process messages with Cloud Functions, start adding more logic until you find the bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the message. Everything works as expected until i send a new email with `service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()` , then it starts looping forever. 

For now i just switched to Zapler (IFTTT works as well), took me 5m to set it up.

Comment: Ok, glad you got an alternative working. I wonder if the send() call just took way too long. Usually, setting a timeout on the operation will help catch those errors.

Comment: Maybe? I anyway did not select the option to retry the function on failure...

Comment: Ok, well you've found an alternative so that's good. :)